# Can I prevent RealVNC from trying to use Reverse VNC?

Tags: vnc, realvnc

I've been going nuts trying to figure out why I can connect to my desktop MacOS system which running RealVNC Server, but not to my laptop which is also using RealVNC.

The desktop has an *older* version of RealVNC Server (6.3.2) with an *expired* license -- and oddly enough, that's the system which ISN'T giving me problems.

My laptop has 7.6.0. I'm trying to connect using non-RealVNC viewers, like TightVNC on a Windows system, and Mocha VNC on my iPhone.

After much barking up many wrong trees (it's not a firewall issue, it's not bad credentials, the server actually is running) I finally figured out that the problem is that my laptop RealVNC server is *actively* rejecting connections from these other VNC clients because it wants to use Reverse VNC, and these other clients are either not available for, or capable of, these reverse connections.

I tried turning off the RealVNC "Allow cloud connections" option, since I don't really need that, and I hoped that would prevent Reverse VNC from being required. It didn't.

Nothing I see in the Expert settings looks like a clear way to make my RealVNC Server simply accept direct connections without trying to make reverse connections. I hope I'm not missing something, and it's actually still possible to make a direct connection.